# Edit rejected because This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17717441) (Yes, it was a very small edit). It was rejected because it got two reject votes and one approve vote.

> Reason: This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to
>   read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are
>   either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

**Why I suggested this edit?**

When I read that answer, I could not get 20000 milliseconds = 20 seconds. I used an online converter to find out.

But after getting the  20000 milliseconds = 20 seconds, I got the point that milli = 1000... I knew that since I was in grade 7,8 but while reading the answer, however, I forgot about it.

So I added *"(20 seconds)"* after the *"20000 milliseconds"* to make it easier for future readers.

But it was rejected.

Should I avoid suggesting this kind of edit in future?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid that kind of edit in the future.

Comment: It's not generally wrong to add clarifying information into posts, but in this specific case it seems superfluous. In the programming world, knowing this is expected.

Comment: It is not only superfluous, but actually ADDS confusion, (why is that there, is the value in seconds relevant somehow? I must re-read the question a few times in case I missed something important, or maybe there is somethng written between the lines?  Is something being implied I did not understand? What am I missing here?).

Answer (score 18):

I agree with the rejection. Let's go through the given reason:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read

I don't believe either 20000 milliseconds or 20 seconds is 'difficult' enough to read to warrant adding the converted value as well. In this case the choice of milliseconds by the answerer is given by the `ttl` value, which is set in ms (so the value also directly corresponds to the image).

> easier to find

No

> more accurate

No

> more accessible

Also no, since as you said yourself, anyone after 6th grade (especially programmers) should know that "milli" = 10^-3. (You might happen to forget it - which isn't a big deal - but that shouldn't be the expectation of the reader)

Therefore the

> Changes are (...) completely superfluous

Even if you had full editing privileges I'd still say that there is no need for such an edit, so it's especially also not worth any reviewer's time in this case.